# Can we replace EXTJS 4.0 + php5 + mysql with RubyOnRails with MySQL

Tags: mysql, web-applications

I might be required to work on EXTJS 4.0 + PHP5 + MySQL to implement a Web App. Right now, I am not that clear about the requirement.

I also have some knowledge of RubyOnRails. I think I can replace it with RubyOnRails. The possible concern is that I am not sure whether RubyOnRails has a rich layout functionalities in the client. I once used CSS, HTML creating view in RubyOnRails.

Comment: That's great! Congratulations on working your way arous this new app! But what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

When you use ExtJS 4 you dont need to be concerened about rails layout capabilities. You will be working with Rails' REST and JSON support most of the time. And you have got the [Netzke](http://netzke.org/) to aid you further.

Comment: Are you saying that we can replace apache+php+mysql with RubyOnRails and connect it with EXTJS? Thanks.